# How can I create an array of pointers point to a 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I really don't know how to explain it. Please bear with me. 
I try to pass the 2 dimensional array into a function `string[][]`, and in that function I going to create a pointer which point to the array I passed in. I will do compare of element in `string[][]`

```
//From main
char string[3][3] = {"cat","dog","bat"};
//From function
declare a pointer which points to string;
if (strcpm(string[1],string[2]) == 1)
    {
        pointer[1] value set to address of string[2];
        pointer[2] value set to address of string[1]
    }
printf("%s", *(pointer));
```

I don't want to modify `string[3][3]`, then the function would quit the function without return anything
I have the idea, but I don't know how to declare `pointer`, please help me. Thanks! 
Visualize

```
In main                     In function
string                      ptr
cat                         1000
dog                         1008
bat                         1012
Do compare
dog > bat
ptr[3] = address of dog;
ptr[2] = addess of bat;
printf("%s", *(ptr+1);
printf("%s", *(ptr+2);
quit function, return nothing
```

Comment: Should `strcpm` be `strcmp`?

Comment: You need to show us the code that calls this function, showing us how the 2D array of strings is created.  You should also show us the outline of the function you are creating to do the work — the one containing the string comparison and assignments to `pointer`.  We can't tell what you're not doing wrong without that information.  A simple array of pointers is `char *pointer[3];` (that'll allow you `pointer[1]` and `pointer[2]`, but remember C indexes arrays from 0, not 1).

Comment: Are you going to somehow return these pointer values you make inside the function? Or are they only used in that function as a part of determining what to print at the end of the function?

Comment: @Matt McNabb I will not return anything

Comment: `char string[3][3] = {"cat","dog","bat"};` should be declared as `char string[3][4] = {"cat","dog","bat"};`, because of the 0 terminator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a function to accept an array of strings  (not an array of pointers to strings, which is different):

```
void func(size_t rows, size_t cols, char strings[rows][cols])
{
    char const *pointers[rows];

    // Initialize each pointer to point to each row
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
         pointers[i] = &strings[i][0];

    // here you can manipulate the pointers, e.g. bubble sort them

    printf("%s\n", pointers[0]);
}
```

Calling this function:

```
int main()
{
    char stuff[4][20] = { "cat", "dog", "snuffleupagus", "horse" };

    func(4, 20, stuff);
}
```

Pro tip: you can compute array dimensions instead of using magic numbers:

```
#define LENGTH_OF(array) ( sizeof(array) / sizeof((array)[0]) )

char stuff[][20] = { "cat", "dog", "snuffleupagus", "horse" };
func( LENGTH_OF(stuff), LENGTH_OF(stuff[0]), stuff );
```

As noted in comments, be careful about the second dimension (`20` in my case). C permits an array of char to be initialized with a string of exactly that length, in which case the array will end up not containing a string (i.e. it will contain characters that are not null-terminated).

Comment: Thank you Mr.McNabb, I got what I want.

Answer (score 0):

in C, strings are represented as an array of characters. This is represented in two normal ways, `char* identifier` and `char identifier[]`. A 2 dimensional Array is declared as a pointer to the string. So, it can be written as

```
char **strArray1
char  *strArray2[]
char   strArray3[][]
```

Each has different implications, that I won't get into here as it's pedantic.

To answer your question as literally as I can, you can write the code in your post as

```
int main (void) {
    char * strArray[2] = { "This is a String", "This is a String too" };
    if (strcmp(strArray[0], strArray[1]) == 0) {
       ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but if I do, I am posting an example where you can pass an array of "strings" (which in C is represented as an array of arrays of char). Then you can compare the two first strings in your array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* my_function(char *strings[]) {
    char *ptrToString = NULL;

    if (strcmp(strings[0],strings[1]) > 0)   // Do you really mean '==1' here?
    {
        ptrToString = strings[1];
    } else {
        ptrToString = strings[0];
    }

    printf ("%s\n", ptrToString);   // No need for '*', %s takes a pointer to char as argument

    return ptrToString;
}

void main (void) {
   char *a[] = {"dog", "cat"};
   my_function(a);
}
```

Notes:
* I changed "strcmp() == 1" to checking if the return is possitive or not. Checking for a specific value is unconventional (might not match your C implementation). In the documentation, the only guarantee is that strcmp will return positive, negative or zero, but not a specific value.
http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp 
* There must be at least two null-treminated strings in the array for my_function function to work without segfaulting.

I hope this guides you in the right direction.